# Is it common to pay for taxi in advance in the Balkan countries?

Tags: taxis, montenegro, balkans, fraud

Is it common in Balkan countries to pay for a taxi in advance? 
We have taken a water taxi and been asked to pay in advance and paid not to the driver, but to his "boss". Then we arrived half way and the driver asked for more money, claiming that is the place we paid to go to, resulting a big argument and big disappoint in local people.

Is that a common fraud scheme when taxi asks for payment in advance and we should steer clear from these guys?

Comment: @pnuts that is the first time I hear about this airport practice. Any particular places you can name that do this?

Comment: @trailmax I have seen this as well, but definitely not in the Balkans.

Comment: @pnuts wow that's a great research with links, I suggest you make a proper answer out this and get deserved up votes

Comment: Never ever paid in advance, although in some countries the price was fixed ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is certainly uncommon enough that I have never seen this happen.** Specifically, since you are asking about Balkan countries and you have tagged your post with *Montenegro*, I can say that this did not happen even once last month when I was traveling through 3 Balkan countries. For water taxis, we were *quoted* the price ahead of time but did not need to pay ahead.

We did take a small group boat which appeared to have a regular schedule. In that case, we bought a ticket a few meters in front of the dock and handed that over on the boat as proof of payment. This is not what I would call a water taxi since it is not scheduled *on demand*.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like our scheme is a fraud, but a rare one. We have asked locals and nobody heard about this before